# How to use intrinsic functions of CloudFormation properly in yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am writing a YAML file for my serverless services. I deployed and tested my REST APIs, all work fine. but why the YAML file always shows errors like this

[image]

I followed links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html

https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-pseudo-parameters

Any suggestions on how to implement it properly, please share it with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t worry, you are using it correctly.

However, your IDE is marking this as an error because it's a CloudFormation-specific extension and not standard YAML.

If you're using VSCode, you can add the following to the settings.json in order to make the error message disappear for CloudFormation’s custom tags:

```
{
    ..., # other settings

    "yaml.customTags": [
        "!And",
        "!If",
        "!Not",
        "!Equals",
        "!Or",
        "!FindInMap",
        "!Base64",
        "!Cidr",
        "!Ref",
        "!Sub",
        "!GetAtt",
        "!GetAZs",
        "!ImportValue",
        "!Select",
        "!Split",
        "!Join",
        "!And sequence",
        "!If sequence",
        "!Not sequence",
        "!Equals sequence",
        "!Or sequence",
        "!FindInMap sequence",
        "!Join sequence",
        "!Sub sequence",
        "!ImportValue sequence",
        "!Select sequence",
        "!Split sequence"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Settings.json file locations
Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here: Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json. macOS $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json.

For Mac users Library folder will be hidden so use cmd+shift+dot to view it.
Hope this helps.